# How to change all elements of struct array, which have certain field value?

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

Imagine that we have an array of structures:

```
S=repmat(struct('a1',0,'a2', 0, 'a3', 0, ...), N, 1 );
```

I need to change all elements with specific field value (e.g. field a1 = k) to elements with another value of this field (e.g. field a1 = m). In other words, if `S(i).a1 == k` => `S(i).a1 = m`. And I need to do it really fast, so no loop suits me. I tried to find a solution and here is what I found. Command:

```
S([S.a1]==k)
```

returns an array containing all elements with field a1 equals k. However, if I change something in this array, of course, nothing will happen in initial array S. So I tried to do obvious move:

```
S([S.a1]==k).a1 = m
```

Unfortunately, MATLAB doesn't understand this:

```
Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma separated list expansion on left hand side.  Missing [] are the most likely cause.
```

(I have tried to put brackets everywhere - no help)

Is there any way to do this without loop (ideally, it should work as fast as possible)? With something like `structfun` maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haha, it seems that you didn't succeed to put brackets everywhere... :-)

Comment: By the way, `structfun` is worse than `for` loops, because it is a *disguised* loop anyway, and you perform the actions by calling a function for each element -- and function calls in MATLAB are expensive.

Comment: @CST-Link thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you wrapped `[S.a1]` with brackets to concatenate the multiple outputs into a vector, you need to wrap `S([S.a1]==k).a1`. Then, with help from [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function, you can copy a single input `m` to multiple outputs. The final solution with the correct synthax looks like this:

```
[S([S(:).a1]==k).a1]=deal(m)
```

Comment: Thank you, really help me. :)

Comment: @Gickle no problem. Consider [`accepting the answer`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you!